# Android RecyclerView Grid Draggable different span size

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I have a recycler view as follows:

```
  -------------
  |  1  |  2  |
  |     |     |
  -------------
  |  3  |  4  |
  |     |     |
  -------------
  |     5     |
  |           |
  -------------
  |     6     |
  |           |
  -------------
  |     7     |
  |           |
  -------------
```

As you can see first 4 items has span size 1, the rest (5,6,7) has span size as 2.
I want to make it draggable, by keeping span sizes. Currently my code keeps the spans, but it updates the adapter in every 1 step change (meaning, if you want to drag 7 to 4, it first replaces 7 with 6 -stops-, then 7 with 5 -stops-, then 7 with 4.) So it doesn't let me to change 7 -> 4 directly. (It's annoying in user's side).

Also if I want to change 7 -> 4, I want 3rd item to stay in the center, since span of 7 does not fit into where 4 was. Just like this:

```
  -------------
  |  1  |  2  |
  |     |     |
  -------------
     |  3  |
     |     |
  -------------
  |     7     |
  |           |    
  -------------
  |     5     |
  |           |
  -------------
  |     6     |
  |           |
  -------------
     |  4  |
     |     |
     -------
```

Here is my ItemTouchHelper:

```
class RecyclerViewItemTouchHelper<T>(private val mAdapter: SimpleRecyclerViewAdapter<T, *>, shouldSwapDiff: Boolean = true) : ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

  override fun isLongPressDragEnabled() = true

  override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled() = false

  override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
    val dragFlags = UP or DOWN or LEFT or RIGHT
    val swipeFlags = if (isItemViewSwipeEnabled) START or END else 0
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags)
  }

  override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
    val fromPosition = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
    val toPosition = target.bindingAdapterPosition

    Collections.swap(mAdapter.data, fromPosition, toPosition)
    mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
    return true
  }

  override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
  }
})
```

So how can I make the dragging smooth and set the item's margins dynamically according to span?

Thanks in advance.